# How can I focus camera and show background color or use an image as background

Tags: rendering, objects, camera, image, lighting

yesterday I created one question and [moonboots](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/34531/moonboots) helped me: [How to use sculpt mode tools in edit mode.](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/258655/how-to-use-sculpt-mode-tools-in-edit-mode/258656?noredirect=1#comment441173_258656)

But after that I have some troubles and made a new question. I tried to create an high resolution image to use as wallpaper, and I used the print screen button in my keyboard, but this made a poor resolution image. Then moonbots tell me to go to camera mode by pressing <kbd>0</kbd> on the number pad and press <kbd>F12</kbd> to render, and I did that.

The image is much cleaner than print screen button, but another problems appears:

1: the character isn't 100% focused: some few parts have blur.

2: the blue background does not appear, in rendering the background is all black

How can I adjust the camera focus and how show the blue background in render or put an picture instead of full black background?

[image: screenshot of render window and 3D workspace]

the background color is black and the character isn't 100% focused

P.S. sorry for asking so many questions

---

[image]

here, how disable depth of field? and the Transparent option is disabled but the background still black

Comment: Hello, you've activated the camera's depth of field, it may explain the blur. For the background, make sure that you've not enabled the Render > Film > Transparent option

Comment: Hi, there is no option to disable the camera's depth of field, and transparent is disabled, i will post an image to be more clear

Comment: maybe share your file, remove some parts of the character if it's copyright: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: hi moonboots, i tried upload a new picture but it was deleted, if i put the file in pasteall.org you can make changes on camera deep field to correct the blur and help with the background black?

Comment: you need to upload, it will generate a URL, copy it and paste it here  ;)

Comment: ok i will do it, the file is chun-li from an deviantart user, he posted the link to download for free an year ago, and i downloaded for free and keep the file, but a few weeks ago he created an patreon link and now the file is no more free, to make an download now you have the pay the patreon, soo how i can uploaded without copyright troubles? what parts i need to change or delete to avoid problems?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135090/discussion-between-gustavo-henrique-ribeiro-and-moonboots).

Answer (score 0):

You have deactivated the rendering of the background, therefore this black background instead of the blue background:

[image]

For the blur, you've made *Camera 0* active but it won't be the one that will render as you have selected another one in the *Scene* panel, *Camera 1*. They both have *Depth of Field* enabled in the *Object Data* panel, deactivate this option or lower down its effect if you want less blur (or bring back the value to something closer to the default *F-Stop* value, which is 2.8:

[image]